# How to rename a file after install to a dynamic name with WIX?

Tags: wix, rename, file-copying

What I want do is the follow:

```
<Component ...>
   <File Id="xyz" Name="[SERVICE].exe" Source="..\prunmgr.exe">
</Component>
```

But `name` does not accept place holder properties. How can I rename the exe file to a dynamic file on installing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad workaround are 2 CustomActions with a command shell. One after InstallFiles rename the file. And a second delete the file before InstallFiles.

Comment: You should do a test repair of your product to see what happens. You may find that the removed file is re-installed. The user might run a repair from a number of places, or Windows may do one in some situations.

Comment: I have add the condition "NOT Installed OR REINSTALL OR REMOVE". Thanks for the tip.